# Initialize a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to initialize a struct but getting the following error messages in C:

> error: initializer element is not constant
>
> error: (near initialization for 'resource01.resource.role')

For URL it works, it's just the role which is not working. First I had a pointer on role and I assigned the address of the variable. I removed the pointer because I don't need it and I can t assign just a value to the variable. What am I doing wrong?

```
static char const resource01Url[] = "/dummy";
static int const resource01Role = 2;
static struct RestResourceNode_S resource01 =
{
    {
        resource01Url,
        resource01Role,
        &DummyHandler_call
    },
    NULL
};

static struct RestResourcesManager_S resourcesManager =
{
    &resource01, &resource01
};
```

The type `RestResourceNode_S` is defined:

```
struct RestResourceNode_S
{
    RestResource_T resource;
    struct RestResourceNode_S const *next;
}
```

and `RestResource_t`:

```
struct RestResource_S
{
    char const *url;

    int const role;

    retcode_t (*handle)(Msg_T *);
};

typedef struct RestResource_S RestResource_T;
```

Comment: `resource01Url` does count as a constant expression, the location of the array is determined by the linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C99 standard §6.7.8 ¶4 says

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Also, `const` are not true constants in C in the sense that they are not compile-time constant. This means that you cannot have a constant object in the initializer of a structure which has static storage allocation. However, if your structure has automatic storage allocation, this would work fine.

What you can do is define your `const` objects as macros -

```
#define resource01Url "/dummy"
#define resource01Role 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`int const` does not count as a compile-time constant in C. You will have to change it to a `#define` instead.

Comment: What do you mean with "change it to a #define "?

Comment: `#define resource01Role 2`

Comment: For `int` enumerations are more appropriate: `enum { resource01Role = 2, };`